# How do I call a function once using jquery on mousewheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a section that, once entered, the body's overflow is set to hidden and the user must scroll to fire a certain animations before proceeding to the next section. I use `var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;` to capture any attempts made to scroll. My problem is that when I use `.on('mousewheel')` I am returned with a number of calls to the function when I only want one. How can I achieve this? Thanks. This is the code that I'm using:

```
$('html').on ('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if($('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-secondPage')) {
        if(delta < 0 ){
            var something = (function() {
                var executed = false;
                return function () {
                    if (!executed) {
                        executed = true;
                        console.log('call me once please');
                    }
                };
            });
            something();
         }

     });
}
```

here is something else i tried:

```
if($body.hasClass('fp-viewing-secondPage')) {
                    if($body.hasClass('setAn1')){
                        $('html').one('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                            console.log('animation 1');
                            $body.addClass('setAn2').removeClass('setAn1');
                        });
                    } if($body.hasClass('setAn2')){
                        $('body').one('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                            console.log('animation 2');
                            $body.addClass('setAn3');
                        });
                    } if($body.hasClass('setAn3')){
                        $('html').one('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                            console.log('animation 3');
                            alert('moving on to next section');
                        });
                    }
                }
```

but this code only runs the first setAn1? is it because of the .one?

Comment: You could use `$('html').one( .. )` but that's probably not at all what you want, as you probably want a "number of calls to the function" to be able to know when the scroll position is what you're checking for, so you probably want to throttle/debounce the event

Comment: You need to have a settimeout method in combination with cleartimeout.

Comment: What do you mean by "one call" ? How do you define a `mousewheel` call, and when should it end? When the user stops scrolling? Do you want it to only happen once per page load?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209939/limit-mousewheel-delta-to-fire-once-per-scroll

Comment: you can also have a variable `var secret= false;`, and that sectioned is entered set it to `true` and only run your function if `secret` is `false`

Answer (score 3):

Check this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cpkw9uv8/), instead of `on('mousewheel`) I've used `on('scroll'` just for demonstration purpose.

So `secret` is set to `false` and as soon as we enter that `div#test` section we will run the function - `console.log()` in this case- and then set `secret` to `true`, thus the function will only be called once.

Then when we leave that section set `secret` back to `false` so that we can run the required function again if we enter the `#test` section more times, but still the function will be fired once only for each time.

```js
var secret = false,
    testTop = $('#test').offset().top,
    testHeight = $('#test').height(),
    scrlTop;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
 scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrlTop > testTop && scrlTop < testTop+testHeight){
   if(!secret){
     console.log('call me once please');
      secret = true;
    }   
  }else{
   secret = false;   
  }
});
```

```css
body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:1500px; background-color:orange; }
#test{ margin-top:700px; height:400px; width:100%; background-color:#090; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

The above code fires the function **once** every time you enter the `#test` section, however if your goal is to run the function only once and that's it no matter if he leaves that section or not, just remove this part: [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cpkw9uv8/1/)

```
else{
    secret = false;
}
```

---

### ----------

**UPDATE 1:**

Having this [**JS Fiddle 3** -*updated 2*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/uyse34dv/) with the following code: -*updated*-

```js
var secret = [false, false, false, false, false],
    sections = $('.sections'),
    secHeight = $('#one').height(),
    body = $('html, body'), //select both html and body cross-browser fix
    links = $('#links a'),
    prevLinkId = 0,
    linkId, secHeight, scrlTop, diff;
    
links.each(function(index){
    $(this).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        secHeight = $('#one').height();
        linkId = $(this).attr('id');
        linkId = linkId.replace('lnk', '');
        links.removeClass('highlight');
        $(links[linkId]).addClass('highlight');
        diff = Math.abs(linkId - prevLinkId);
        timeDelay = diff * 250;
        distance = index * secHeight;
        body.animate({scrollTop: distance} , timeDelay);
        prevLinkId = linkId;
    });
});
    
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    playOnce();
});

$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
    scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        //scroll down
        body.animate({scrollTop: scrlTop + 50} , 20);
    }else {
        //scroll up
        body.animate({scrollTop: scrlTop - 50} , 20);
    }
    playOnce();
});

function playOnce(){
    secHeight = $('#one').height();
    if(scrlTop >= 0 && scrlTop < secHeight){
        if(secret[0] == false){
            console.log('this is Section One');
            secret = [true, false, false, false, false];
        }
    }else if(scrlTop >= secHeight && scrlTop < 2 * secHeight){
        if(secret[1] == false){
            console.log('this is Section Two');
            secret = [false, true, false, false, false];
        }
    }
    else if(scrlTop >= 2 * secHeight && scrlTop < 3 * secHeight){
        if(secret[2] == false){
            console.log('this is Section Three');
            secret = [false, false, true, false, false];
        }
    }
    else if(scrlTop >= 3 * secHeight && scrlTop < 4 * secHeight){
        if(secret[3] == false){
            console.log('this is Section Four');
            secret = [false, false, false, true, false];
        }
    }else if(scrlTop >= 4 * secHeight && scrlTop < 5 * secHeight){
        if(secret[4] == false){
            console.log('this is Section Five');
            secret = [false, false, false, false, true];
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#links{
  width:65px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:-10px;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  color:white;
  padding-left:20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor:default;
}
#links:hover{
  width:190px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#links a{
  width:22px;
  line-height:22px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#444;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#links a:hover, #links .highlight{
  background-color:black;
  color:#EEE;
}
.sections{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:72px;
  line-height:100vh;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
#one{background-color:green}
#two{background-color:orange}
#three{background-color:tomato}
#four{background-color:skyblue}
#five{background-color:navy}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  Section
  <a id="lnk0" href="#one" class="highlight">1</a>
  <a id="lnk1" href="#two">2</a>
  <a id="lnk2" href="#three">3</a>
  <a id="lnk3" href="#four">4</a>
  <a id="lnk4" href="#five">5</a>
</div>
<div id="one" class="sections">Section ONE</div>
<div id="two" class="sections">Section TWO</div>
<div id="three" class="sections">Section THREE</div>
<div id="four" class="sections">Section FOUR</div>
<div id="five" class="sections">Section Five</div>
```

**TL;DR**
With 5 `.sections` divs simulating fullpage sections, and an array of toggles -*or flags*- `secret = [false, false, false, false, false]`, as having `body{overflow:hidden}` will not make the page to scroll, we need to listen to the `mouseweel` event and detect the direction of the scrolling using this code:

```
// Listening to DOMMouseScroll and mousewheel events together will make
// this code work correctly cross-browser.
// same thing for e.originalEvent.detail and e.originalEvent.wheelDelta
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
    scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        //scrolling down
        body.animate({scrollTop: scrlTop + 50} , 20);
    }else {
        //scrolling up
        body.animate({scrollTop: scrlTop - 50} , 20);
    }
    // calling playOnce function
    playOnce();
});
```

Now in `playOnce()` function we have 5 levels if-statement, each level checks the `scrollTop()` value to see whether window is on the corresponding `.section` div, i.e:

```
else if(scrlTop >= 3 * secHeight && scrlTop < 4 * secHeight){
if(secret[3] == false){ // 3 because arrays starts from zero
    console.log('this is Section Four');
    // we set the 4th element in the secret array to true and the rest to
    // false, thus we ensure that we don't fire the function more than once
    // as long as the user has not left the 4th element upward or down
    secret = [false, false, false, true, false]; 
}
```

---

### ----------

**UPDATE 2:**

If you don't want to call the function -*repeat the animation*- when the user leaves a certain section then scrolls back into it, have a look at this [**JS fiddle 4**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3yx63h3s/1/), the only change you need to make in javascript is, in a certain section, instead of setting it respective element in the `secret` array to `true` and setting all others to `false`, we set the section/s which is/are before it concerning the DOM ranking., so for section#3 the `secret` array will be:

```
secret = [true, true, true, false, false];
```

instead of:

```
secret = [false, false, true, false, false];
```

in the previous solution which lets you call the function every time you scroll back into a section after leaving it.

Comment: This is nice, however i need to be able to detect the mousewheel while the body overflow is hidden. when i try one("mousewheel") it doesnt even call the function

Comment: It calls it but it doesn't scroll up or down because `overflow:hidden`, you want the body overflow`` to stay `hidden` even after you use the mouse wheel?

Comment: check the console `on('mousewheel')` https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/p278Le3y/1/

Comment: this is actually apart of fullpage.js project. when the person arrives to the second section. I make the body overflow hidden so that the user can use scroll down events to trigger animations. on the last animation then i will trigger the section change and continue down the page. but the problem was capturing single instances of scrolling. when using .on(wheelmouse) or on(scroll) on the first scroll the all the animations would roll through because the mousewhell was counting multiple times per scroll

Comment: 262(index):58 Yaay! I've been triggered. I did it's still the same problem. its saying yaay 262 times

Comment: thatfiddle was just to prove that the `on('mouswhee')` event is being fired but the page doesn't scroll because you said "*i need to be able to detect the mousewheel while the body overflow is hidden*"

Comment: You can still make use of `$(window).scrollTop()`, and compare its value to each of your sections `offset().top` values, give me some and I'll show you an example.

Comment: I tried the .one method with some if statements but this time i can only run the code once. i guessing i can only use .one once per selector? also how can i use scrolltop if the window isnt moving?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the event handler to be called once, you can use jQuery's `.one()` function:

```
$('html').one ('mousewheel', function (e) {
    // gets called once here..
});
```

jQuery one function: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I made edits and tried the .one method however after the first if statement the code no longer runs? I can not have mutiple.one() for the selector html?

Comment: Wrong logic. He does not want to fire the callback for mousewheel once. He wants the first time the user scrolls down.

Comment: I want to be able to see the first scroll attempt and fire an animation, see the second attempt and fire a second animation and finally a third one then do something else.

Comment: Your 'executed' variable is clobbered each time the event is raised. Use a global variable instead (e.g. window.executed) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a programming pattern called [Throttling](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls), in which one function can only be called once every X seconds.

In your case specifically, your code is not working because you are instantiating `var executed` inside the closure (A.K.A every time you execute `something()`). You need to save your variable into the global scope (using `window.executed` instead of just `executed` is an easy but ugly way to do it)